# How to subtract two uint16 numpy arrays to give a int16 numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `type=np.uint16' numpy arrays that I have to subtract (let's call them A and B).
I have to account for the possibility that performing A - B could result in some negative entries. To avoid overflow, I would like to be able to perform

```
diff = A - B
```

such that diff would be converted to a np.int16 numpy array.
How could I do this efficiently in Python?

If I do this:

```
diff = np.zeros(height*width, dtype=np.int16)
```

and then perform,

```
diff = A - B
```

I still get overflow. I have purposely set some values of B to be greater than those in A so that OF would occur.

Comment: so `np.uint16` can't contain negative values.. what do you want?

Comment: @farhawa That's correct because I know for sure that A and B don't contain negative values. But it could be that some values in B are larger than the respective in A so doing `diff = A - B` would result in overflow for some values. I wan't diff to be able to hold negative values as well and not overflow essentially.

Comment: One (and only one) solution would be to use an other `dtype`

Comment: @farhawa.. I see! Would using np.int32 be slower than using np.uint16 for when I calculate A and B? Or do you think using float would be better?

Comment: no! the `dtype` of a numpy array have more effect on the memory usage.

Comment: @farhawa Was the "no!" for the first or second question?

Comment: int32 shouldn't be any faster or slower on modern CPU and front-side buses than int16, but you can benchmark. float32 will fail to capture all integers >=`2**24` (i.e., `int(np.float32(2**24+1)) - (2**24+1)`) so you probably don't want that. But int32 will take 2x memory. It should be easy enough to test all three possibilities and benchmark them all.